# Probability of cycle on a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

The cycle time for trucks hauling concrete to a building site is uniformly distributed over the interval 50 to 70 minutes.

1. What is the probability that the cycle time exceeds 65 minutes if it is known that it exceeds 55 minutes?
2. find the mean cycle times.

For the first question:
I know that over a uniform distribution we have $\frac{1}{b-a}$ I'm guessing this implies that over the interval of 50 to 70 minutes I have $\frac{1}{70-50}=\frac{1}{20}$.

To calculate the probability, then I integrate over the interval from $\frac{1}{20}\int_{55}^{65} dx$?

Whereas if I take the mean, then I integrate likeso $\frac{1}{20}\int_{55}^{65}xdx$

I'm unsure, so I'd really appreciate some help towards this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X\sim U(50,70)$ be the random variable representing the cycle time of the trucks hauling. We are searching for the following probability: $$P(X>65|X>55)$$

Now, since we know that $X>55$, we deduce that the PDF is $\frac{1}{70-55}=\frac{1}{15}$. We now just have to calculate the probability that $X>65$. This is simply $$\frac{70-65}{15}=\frac{5}{15}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Now, I assume that we're searching for the mean given $X>55$. This is $$\frac{1}{2}(a+b)=\frac{1}{2}(55+70)=62.5$$

Comment: Ah yes! This makes better sense. I was unfamiliar of your approach until I looked back on my notes.